# SQL consolidate consecutive date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date

Hi could anyone help me with the SQL Query.
I want to display all the consecutive dates in the db where there is at least 2 consecutive dates. 
Below are an example of the output what i was hoping for.

here is a list of dates:

```
2016-06-24 00:00:00.000
2016-06-24 00:00:00.000
2016-06-24 00:00:00.000
2016-06-25 00:00:00.000
2016-06-25 00:00:00.000
2016-06-26 00:00:00.000
2016-05-26 00:00:00.000
2016-05-25 00:00:00.000
2016-04-04 00:00:00.000
2016-06-26 00:00:00.000
```

**----------output----------**

```
| Start Date              | End Date                | Count | consecutive Date |
| 2016-05-25 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-25 00:00:00.000 | 1     | 2                |
| 2016-05-25 00:00:00.000 | 2016-05-26 00:00:00.000 | 1     | 2                |
| 2016-06-24 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-25 00:00:00.000 | 2     | 2                |
| 2016-06-24 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 2     | 3                |
| 2016-06-25 00:00:00.000 | 2016-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 2     | 2                |
```

This is what I have currently:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, dateAvailable), '+08:00') d,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dateAvailable) i
  FROM user_dateTbl
  GROUP BY dateAvailable
)
SELECT MIN(d),MAX(d)
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)
```

please help me out thank you.
 If your unsure of what I am writing do feel free to write in the comment below.

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot understand your output

Comment: please explain your output   ?

Comment: i wanted to display all the dates that have at least 2 consecutive date and count how many people have selected that particular dates

Comment: And how you determine `StartDate` and `EndDate`?